# Twilio unable to forward/transfer call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, twilio, twilio-twiml

I have an app that dials a phone number, gives a set of instructions, and then forwards the call to a specified phone number.  Currently when I press the digit to transfer the call it just pauses and hangs up.  Not sure what im doing wrong.

1. This is the initial instructions.  If the number 1 is pressed it is supposed to transfer to transfer.xml, which is under # 2.

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Response>
       <Gather timeout="10" action="http://1.1.1.1/twimlet/transfer.xml" numDigits='1' finishOnKey='1'>
               <Say>"Dummy Text Dummy Text"</Say>
               <Say>"Please press 1 to transfer this call. Or nothing to hang up."</Say>
       </Gather>
   </Response>`
2. If the caller presses #1 then it is supposed to send them to this xml file, and transfer the current call to the number under dial.  But currently it just hangs for 2 seconds and drops the call.

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Response>
       <Say>"Transferring you to a court clerk"</Say>
       <Dial timeout="60" callerID='+14393523419'>
          <Number>8125277222</Number>
       </Dial>
   </Response>`

Am I doing something wrong with my xml? Not sure why it is dropping.

Comment: Have you checked Monitor within your Twilio dashboard? Something like this is normally because something returned an error and checking the alerts in Monitor might show what happened.

Comment: Yes no errors... Iptables are off as well.  I thought maybe my syntax was wrong?

Comment: Could you send your Account SID to philnash@twilio.com and I'll have a look in the back end to see if I can find what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Your action in your `<Gather>` is pointing towards the URL `http://1.1.1.1/twimlet/transfer.xml`. That looks like a local network address rather than a publicly available URL. If that IP address is not available to Twilio, then the call will not be able to continue.

Try using relative URLs instead of absolute ones. Twilio will happily follow the path `/twimlet/transfer.xml`.

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: hey @philnash, the ip address is publicly available, I changed it to `1.1.1.1` because I was posting on stack.

Answer (score 0):

Hm could it be because `finishOnKey` is set to 1 in your `<Gather>` verb? So, it's taking it as you end the call? Have you tried setting it to `finishOnKey=""`?

Comment: I had the same thought.  So I removed finishOnKey and still same result.